# Ordering of webparts inside webzone issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a page layout with a webpart zone in it. As per the requirement there should be 4 custom webparts in that webzone.I have placed the webparts in the order as per the requirement. But when I try to create a new publishing page with this layout, I could see
that the order of webpart  I have given in layout is not same as in the newly created page. So once again I have to order these webparts in edit mode .Changed the zone index property for the webparts in layout but it’s still not coming in order in the newly created  page.

Ex:
Ordering of webparts in the page layout.
 [image]

Ordering of webparts after the page is created using the layout.

[image]

Any help for fixing this ordering issue will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So you have preloaded the web part zone in the page layout with the four web parts in the order you wish? If so and the order is not correct then you might have to create an event receiver that can trap when the page is being created and then add the web parts manually via code. that would at least ensure the order but seems overkill to me.

If the web parts are included in the web part zones within a page layout though, they should be added in that order when the page is created.